# Response headers in Memcached+Nginx

Tags: nginx, memcached, http-headers

Is there any way to cache response headers along with the response body in Memcached for use with Nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want cache responses in memcached you have to store your information in it manually by using something like a script. Nginx is not web accelerator like squid or varnish if you need that functionality out of the box take a look at varnish. It is working perfectly with nginx also.

Comment: Yes, I know it. I'm using Django as a backend and write the response to Memcached from there. But how can I cache response headers too? Because by default Nginx adds only it's own headers to response body read from Memcached.

Comment: It seems I got you but what exactly http headers are you talking about ?

Comment: For a sample, I wish to control client caching, i.e. use such headers as "Expires", "Cache-Control", proper "Last-Modified" is also appreciated. Of course, with different values for different pages.

Comment: I'm afraid you should use http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule  instead OR use another memcached plugin https://github.com/bpaquet/ngx_http_enhanced_memcached_module

Comment: I mean vanila ngx_http_memcached_module do not allow to store HTTP headers with data. For example, pages served by Nginx via Memcached storage have the default Nginx Content-Type.

Comment: Thank you very much! ngx_http_enhanced_memcached_module works like a charm for me :)